# C# moving from 2005 to 2017 oop dev especially about classes

Tags: c#, oop, migration

I have a fully coded C# app designed tested and ready to release Zero Errors

HOWEVER

When I compile the app in 2017 I get (null reference error )

I instantiate the class as follows

```
   FlavorPack.BackOfficeLocalDatabase.ImportData UserInfo = 
                     new BackOfficeLocalDatabase.ImportData();
```

Yes I could remove the leading qualifiers by including them in 
using statements but in this instance i=I find it easier to read like this

The Class "ImportData"   is in the "BackOfficeLocalDatabase"  namespace 
I'm sure u understand what I mean

In importData I want to execute a method called GetUserInfo()
it queries sl Db and populates a List (no I dont want it returned 
it lives in the class

So I execute the method as

//load data from server

```
   UserInfo.GetUserInfo();
```

Now let me explain in 2015 this works perfectly in debug and release mode

HOWEVER

that same command when executed in c# 2017

## throws "NullReferenceException "

code from the windows form

```
    //the data is on the sql server 
    //get the data from the server
    //data from USER INFO 
    FlavorPack.BackOfficeLocalDatabase.ImportData UserInfo = new BackOfficeLocalDatabase.ImportData();
    try
    {
            //first find out if this is first startup of this app


            //this truncate has been changed 
            //you cant truncate right away 
            //  UserInfo.TruncateUserInfo();   //truncate local copy user info
            //and get latest copy of user data 
            //truncate now happens from the EF Class

            //load data from server
            UserInfo.GetUserInfo();
            MessageBox.Show("Copied data from sql server");
            UserInfo.ImportToUserLocalDb();


    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {

        dbErr = exp.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(dbErr);
    }
```

==============================================================
code in the class

public void GetUserInfo()
        {
            string cnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlDb"].ConnectionString;

```
        using (SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(cnString))
        {
            sqlconn.Open();


            ////truncate local database
            //TruncateUserInfo();
            ///THIS MUST go onto async

            using (SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Users]", sqlconn))
            {
                //code here

                using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        string line = "";
                        line += line = (sqlReader["Name"]).ToString() + "|";
                        line += line = (sqlReader["Surname"]).ToString() + "|";
                        line += line = (sqlReader["Role"]).ToString() + "|";
                        line += line = (sqlReader["Department"]).ToString() + "|";
                        line += line = (sqlReader["Cell"]).ToString() + "|";
                        line += line = (sqlReader["Email"]).ToString() + "|";
                        line += line = (sqlReader["Image"]).ToString() + "|";
                        line += line = (sqlReader["Date"]).ToString() + "|";
                        line += line = (sqlReader["Password"]).ToString();

                        try
                        {
                            UserContent.Add(line);
                        }
                        catch (Exception exp)
                        {

                            string err = exp.ToString();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your database-connection working as it was in VS2015? If yes, debug, and show us the exact line where you get the exception. It could be anywhere in the execution of `GetUserInfo()`.

Comment: said exception is definitely not for this line `UserInfo.GetUserInfo();`

Comment: Hi Thanks for response BUT no its not the DB connection. It crashes before i attempt to connect to the db. I've stepped thru the code IT doesn't even instantiate the class . Its not as if i instantioated the class and then the connection to db failed . It fails on insantiate ....and its deafault constructor so no its not doidng anything wierd on create cl;ass

Comment: Ill  load the code...

Comment: Please include the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Ok ...sighs so its odder than i recall.....i had to much good weekend and forgot this bit ..... the app works fine on my pc , 2015, it works fine on my pc 2017 THE WHEELS FALL OFF when running on client pc ... I create setup using install shield when it runs on client pc i get the null ref error ....    link to err msg      https://www.dropbox.com/s/7upmtm6jl91eox7/errmsg.png?dl=0

Comment: Well, then all the standard questions apply: do you have the correct connection string in your config, does the connection work, and how can you prove that, does your command get executed correctly, and are all those columns in the result really defined on that client database? In other words, make your code more robust by adding some error handling to it.